# Shortcut to insert at previous and at next line in IntelliJ IDEA (small o and big O with vim)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Iam using IntelliJ IDEA and Iam finding it very useful to write `Java` code. However I got used to `vim` nice shortucts and Iam frankly missing them. In `vim` to create a new line before the current one it's just `O`. To create a new line after the current one, it's `o`. How do I do this with `idea`?

Comment: You just hit the return key where you want the new line.

Comment: @James K Polk that only works at the end of the line :|

Comment: Haha, ok, if your brain is hard-wired to vim you might experiment with [this plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/164-ideavim).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new line before the current one: `ctrl-alt-enter`

Create a new line after the current one: `shift-enter`

Comment: Not as mnemonic as vim but I guess with time I get used to them anyways.